# Looking for native number picker for React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for a component/library which allows a good experience on mobile for inputting numbers (this will be for entering scores, preferably decimal numbers would be allowed too).

I would like something that looks like the one from React Native here https://dev.to/skptricks/react-native-textinput-that-only-accepts-numeric-characters-5698

I have looked at Material UI TextField (type = Number) but it's not very good on mobile as the provided keyboard allows you to enter text (which disappears when you blur). I want the user to see a keyboard which only provides numbers (like when you are entering a phone number on your mobile).

Any recommendations greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use `inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric' }}` in material ui `TextField` to provide only numeric input in virtual keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know if there is a way to allow decimal places too?

Comment: Oh I got it. inputProps={{ inputMode: "decimal" }}. Now I understand that these props are just passed to the input element so you can use and of these input modes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Glad you solved it.